# Why does https not work in this simple reverse proxy setup with Traefik?

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik

I've set up a reverse proxy with Traefik, with multiple nodes running on a local network. Everything works fine with http, but trying to connect over https simply times out. The Traefik logs don't show any errors or messages related to https/acme. Any help would be great!

```
debug = false
logLevel = "INFO"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    #[entryPoints.http.redirect]
    #   entryPoint = "https"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
    caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
    email = "almar@mydomain.com"
    storage = "/etc/traefik/acme.json"
    entryPoint = "https"
    onHostRule = true
    [acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"


[file]

[frontends]
    [frontends.test1]
        backend = "backend1"
        passHostHeader = true
        [frontends.test1.routes.r0]
        rule = "Host:mydomain.com,test1.mydomain.com"    
    [frontends.test2]
        backend = "backend2"
        passHostHeader = true
        [frontends.test2.routes.r0]
        rule = "Host:test2.mydomain.com"

[backends]
    [backends.backend1]
        [backends.backend1.servers.s0]
        url = "http://test1-hostname:80"    
    [backends.backend2]
        [backends.backend2.servers.s0]
        url = "http://test2-hostname:80"
```

Comment: I can confirm that the acme.json is populated with certificates by Traefik.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me; I forgot to expose port 443 (`-p 443:443`) when running the container...